# A User System for jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Would it be possible to implement a user system for the jQuery File upload plugin? I'm looking at something extremely simple, a registration box so a user can register. If they have a certain rank then they can upload using the jQuery File Upload form, and each user has only their files displayed for them (and not everyone's)

I was thinking of creating a simple registration system with mysql, but I was wondering how I would handle logins and session IDs, and pass the user_id to the jQuery File Upload when the file get's uploaded so it can be attached to the right person.

I see this in the wiki: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-user-directories

But I'm not exactly sure how that would work with my implementation.

If someone has any sort of solution or knows websites / sources that cover something like this, it'd be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a url variable to your jQuery file upload and hence can send in variables to your server handler.

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                data.url = "handler.php?UserId=" + id;
                data.submit();
            });
        }
    });
});
```